# Can default value for exported attr for BroadcastReceiver declared in manifest be overridden

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

If a BroadcastReceiver is declared in AndroidManifest.xml with intent-filter specified, for example

```
<receiver
        android:name=".receiver.LocationProviderChangeReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#exported

> The default value depends on whether the broadcast receiver contains intent filters. The absence of any filters means that it can be invoked only by Intent objects that specify its exact class name. This implies that the receiver is intended only for application-internal use (since others would not normally know the class name). So in this case, the default value is "false". On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter implies that the broadcast receiver is intended to receive intents broadcast by the system or other applications, so the default value is "true".

I understand that if the action name is defined as custom one for intent-filter, we should specify `exported` as `false` as it is `true` by default.

But in the above case, the action name tells that it is intended to be called from android OS and hence it doesn't give any warning even if exported flag is not specified (by default it's true)

Specifying the value for `exported` in this case as `false` does not make any difference and the app still gets the broadcast from OS.

According to the docs:

> Whether or not the broadcast receiver can receive messages from sources outside its application — "true" if it can, and "false" if not. If "false", the only messages the broadcast receiver can receive are those sent by components of the same application or applications with the same user ID.

My assumption is that broadcast sent by android system is a source that is outside the application. What is exactly happening here?

- Is the default value for `exported` in this case not overridden by the value explicitly specified?
- Does application still get broadcasts from Android System even if the receiver is not exported? (and only restrict other apps to send broadcasts)

Comment: It is not really clear what you wanted to achieve with the `android:exported` - if you were wondering whether it is possible to change it programmatically, I don't think it is (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126030/broadcastreceiver-set-androidprocess-programmatically)). As the documentation states, the presence of at least on filter automatically defaults the value to true. So for the application to receive Android OS broadcast (like Phone State, etc) you should have specified this in the filters. Using `android:permissions' is another way of restricting external exposure.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla its not about what I want to achieve, its the behaviour that I wanna be sure of, what documentation says is that the default value of exported is true, what I wanna know is that does the value gets overridden to false if I explicitly do so and Android broadcasts are still received, or that the value is never overridden and hence no point of specifying exported=false.

Answer (score 2):

The `android:exported` attribute is used to indicate/limit a broadcast receiver's external exposure. The default value of `android:exported` is not `true`, nor is it `false` here the documentation is very clear. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html), the default value of `android:exported` **depends on whether the broadcast receiver contains intent filters**. Furthermore, if there are no filters, then the value `false` is the default. So although it might seem that there is no point, the idea is that during design time, you can decide which behavior you desire (by specifying filters - or if not applicable, explicitly setting `android:exported` to `false`). Of course setting `android:exported` to `false` whilst specifying filters is not useful because specifying at least one filter implies that the broadcast receiver is intended to receive intents broadcast by the system or other applications.

Comment: I have never anywhere said while asking question that default value of exported is true or false if intent-filter is not specified. I have clearly written that value is true by default **when** intent-filter is specified.

Also specifying exported as false is useful if you are specifying an action that is to be used from within the application (and its not intended to receive broadcasts from android OS or other applications)

Comment: Noted. So at what point will you be able to say that your question has been addressed satisfactorily? This can help all of us to understand your expectations.